# probelm in login actoin in ReactJS with GraphQL

Tags: react-native, graphql, expo

I'm having trouble making the login work in my ReactJS app using GraphQL. Even though the server works fine, and my code looks good, the login isn't working.

Here's the GraphQL code for the login:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client"
const LOGIN = gql`mutation Login($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(user: { username: $username, password: $password }) {
      user {
        id
        role
        firstName
        lastName
        email
        tel
        status       
      }
      token
      permissionsToken
      refreshToken
    }
  }`
export { LOGIN}
```

And here's how I'm using it in the login page:

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { LOGIN } from '../user/mutation.js';
const [login, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(LOGIN);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(" ~ LoginScreen ~ error:", error)
    console.log(" ~ LoginScreen ~ data:", data)
  }, [data, error])

  const onPressSend = async (formData) => {
    try {    
      const { userName, password } = formData;
      console.log(" ~ onPressSend ~ variables:", { userName, password });
      await login({ variables: { userName, password } });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('err:', error);
    }
  };
```

i got this in the consol loge:

`LOG  ~ onPressSend ~ variables: {"password": "Roxed123?", "userName": "+11166554411"}`

`LOG  ~ LoginScreen ~ error: undefined`

`LOG  ~ LoginScreen ~ data: undefined`

Also, the Apollo setup in my app is working fine, as I've successfully used it for another API integration.

Comment: what does this returns 'await login({ variables: { userName, password } });'

instead of useEffect set the state in the try.